# Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, mobile

I have a react-native app with this line of code in my gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and when i try to run it it gives me the error

```
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=512m'
```

Since it says that it's unrecognized i try to remove this option from the said line of code above, and then it gives me this error

```
BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 64
```

I'm not so sure what's wrong anymore and I'm desperate to make this work. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the problem but my laptop is apple silicone

Comment: Remove the `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` option.  It is setting the size of the permgen heap ... which was removed in Java 7.  The classfile error is something different.  It means you are loading .class files that are a newer version that the JRE / JDK understands.  (Version 64 is Java 20.)

Comment: Hi @StephenC I did remove it, and then in my question above, I also mentioned that I run into another error

Comment: And I then mentioned that the other error is unrelated to your original error.   (I'm not sure why you asked a question about a problem that you had already fixed!   Especially if you didn't want / need an answer to it.)

Comment: As for the part of your question about the classfile version number, we need more information; e.g. the Java version that gradle is running on, the target Java version for the build, how the JAR (or whatever) with Java 20 built .classfiles has gotten into your Android build ...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the MaxPermSize to 1024m from 512m

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

delete the .lock files from `android-> app` folder